# PHP-HTML form submits but doesn't show value on first refresh

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple form that adds new comments on button submit. When I submit the form, the page reloads. However the result is not visible on the first refresh. When I refresh the page again, (without form re-submission) then I get to see the result. Any ideas why it behaves like that?

```
    <form id="formid" action="" method="POST" >
      <div>
        <textarea name="discussion" id="discussion"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div>
       <button type="submit" name="new_comment_submit" value="new_comment_submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The data are send as JSON and on the view I retrieve them via GET

Comment: *"I retrieve them via GET"* - And you're using a POST method?

Comment: Where is the PHP for this?

Comment: `<button type="hidden"` < I heard of `<input>` being hidden, just not `<button>`. Pretty sure you want a "submit" type here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner my bad it is "submit"

Comment: What about my first 2 comments?

Comment: This question is unclear. Please give us more information/code.

Comment: You came and asked for help and didn't update your question some 20+ mins. ago. I can't guess. Now someone gave an answer; see that.

Comment: well, he could get a better answer if he would show us his code...

Answer (score -1):

You should use header() function to direct after data saved in database on form view

Comment: depends on how his php looks like. That solution is just a work-around.

Comment: Yes, You should redirect on view page after save form data

Comment: not always. You can't use a header() function after HTML tags, which could become a problem. How is your index file going to like when you have a lot of forms. Yes, you could say that on every Post you'll use header() but what happens when you have a sort page etc.? Again... just a work-around